# Problema al hacer una consulta con una sentencia preparada PHP con subquery

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Gracias gente por contestar, voy a poner la SQL entera. Nunca había hecho una sentencia preparada con SUBQUERY y no se por donde pillarlo.

```
$sqlDatosUsuario = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_DATOS_USUARIO." ( idDatosUsuario, idGenero, nombre, apellido_1, apellido_2, telefono)".
                            "VALUES".
                            "(SELECT idUsuario FROM ".TBL_USUARIO." where nick = :nick),
                            (SELECT idGeneroTmp FROM ".TBL_GENERO." WHERE genero = :genero),
                             :idDatosUsuario, :idGenero, :nombre, :apellido_1, :apellido_2, :telefono);";
                    echo $sqlDatosUsuario;
                        $stDatosUsuario = $con->prepare($sqlDatosUsuario);
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":idDatosUsuario",$this->data["nick"], PDO::PARAM_STR);                      
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":nick", $this->data["nick"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":genero", $this->data["genero"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":idGenero", $this->data["genero"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":nombre", $this->data["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":apellido_1", $this->data["apellido_1"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":apellido_2", $this->data["apellido_2"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stDatosUsuario->bindValue(":telefono", $this->data["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        
                        $testDatosUsuario = $stDatosUsuario->execute();
```

Comment: es esa la query que te da problemas? porque como tal tienes una `,` despues de idDatosUsuario que te puede dar problemas... por otra parte, el subselect tiene dos parentesis de inicio y solo uno al final... (aparte que no esta cerrada con ")

Comment: Aparte de lo que dice @Jakala, ¿dónde usas el parámetro `:idDatosUsuario` en la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Te da problemas porque estás declarando el parámetro ":idDatosUsuario" y usando "idDatosUsuario". Tendría que ser así:

```
$sqlDatosUsuario = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_DATOS_USUARIO." (:idDatosUsuario) VALUES ((SELECT idUsuario FROM ".TBL_USUARIO." where nick = :nick);
```